# Problem overloading D[] using UpValues

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, syntax, upvalues

First I define an entry of `UpValues` overloading `D[]` for expressions with head `ftest`:

```
ftest /: D[ftest[aaa_, bbb_], r] := ftest[D[aaa, r], D[bbb, r]]
```

When I try:

```
D[ftest[r, r^2], r]
```

the result is as I expect it to be:

> ftest[1, 2 r]

However, when I try:

```
D[(r + ftest[r, r^2]), r]
```

Mathematica gives not the result I expect:

> 1 + 2*r*Derivative[0, 1][ftest][r, r^2] + Derivative[1, 0][ftest][r, r^2]

**edit** The result I expect is:

> 1 + ftest[1, 2 r]

(this clarification was suggested by Mr.Wizard, thanks!) **end edit**

**How should I understand this?**

**How can this be fixed?**

---

I tried

```
TreeForm@Unevaluated@Unevaluated@D[(r + ftest[r, r^2]), r]
```

and understand the result:

[image: img_1 for question on overloading D[]]

I also tried

```
TreeForm@Unevaluated@Unevaluated@D[(r + ftest[r, r^2]), r]
```

and I don't understand what does Mathematica do in the meantime to produce this result:

[image: img_2 for question on overloading D[]]

Comment: Just to be clear, what do you expect for `D[(r + ftest[r, r^2]), r]`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, probably OP was expecting the linearity of `D[]` to kick in, so `1 + ftest[1, 2 r]` I guess...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I expect the result to be `1 + ftest[1, 2r]`, just as J.M. wrote

Comment: OK, I can do `D[#, r] & /@ (r + ftest[r, r^2])`, but this is not the solution I hope for, I want to make creation of `Derivative[_,_][ftest][_,_]` not possible for `D[]`

Comment: Is there some reason you cannot make assignments to `Derivative` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## An answer using Mr.Wizard's suggestion

This is an answer to the second question, with assignments to `Derivative[__][ftest][__]`, as suggested by Mr.Wizard in the comments:

```
ftest2 /: Times[ a_ , ftest2[b_, c_] ] := ftest2[a b, a c];
ftest2 /: Plus[ ftest2[a1_, b1_], ftest2[a2_, b2_] ] := ftest2[a1+a2, b1+b2];
Derivative[1,0][ftest2][_,_] = ftest2[1,0];
Derivative[0,1][ftest2][_,_] = ftest2[0,1];
```

The result is as I wrote in the original post I wanted it to be:

```
D[r + ftest2[r, r^2], r]
(* 1 + ftest2[1, 2 r] *)
```

Note that this does **not** require any overloading of `D[]` similar to the instruction from the original post.

---

## Why am I still looking for a better answer?

Nevertheless I'd prefer to overload `D[]`, since this would be faster. I'll show it using an example.

First an object with `Derivative` definitions:

```
LongTestA /: Plus[ LongTestA[a1_, a2_, a3_, a4_] , 
                   LongTestA[b1_, b2_, b3_, b4_] ] 
             :=   LongTestA[a1 + b1, a2 + b2, a3 + b3, a4 + b4];

LongTestA /: Times[ aaa_ , LongTestA[a1_, a2_, a3_, a4_] ] 
             := LongTestA[aaa a1, aaa a2, aaa a3, aaa a4];

Derivative[1, 0, 0, 0][LongTestA][_, _, _, _] = LongTestA[1, 0, 0, 0];
Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0][LongTestA][_, _, _, _] = LongTestA[0, 1, 0, 0];
Derivative[0, 0, 1, 0][LongTestA][_, _, _, _] = LongTestA[0, 0, 1, 0];
Derivative[0, 0, 0, 1][LongTestA][_, _, _, _] = LongTestA[0, 0, 0, 1];
```

Next an object with `D[]` overloading:

```
LongTestB /: D[ LongTestB[a1_, a2_, a3_, a4_] , r ] 
             := LongTestB[ D[a1, r], D[a2, r], D[a3, r], D[a4, r]];
```

A function generating some random 'data' (random polynomials of order `length`):

```
TestPolynomials[length_] := Block[{pol1, pol2, pol3, pol4},
  {pol1, pol2, pol3, pol4} = RandomInteger[100, length] & /@ Range[4];
  {pol1, pol2, pol3, pol4} = Function[list, Array[Times[r^#, list[[#]]] &, {length}]] 
                              /@ {pol1, pol2, pol3, pol4};
  {pol1, pol2, pol3, pol4} = Plus @@@ {pol1, pol2, pol3, pol4};
  Return[{pol1, pol2, pol3, pol4}];
];
```

Functions testing the speed of `D[ LongTestA[__] ,r ]` and `D[ LongTestB[__] ,r ]`:

```
TestLength = 10000;

TestA[_] := Block[{tmp},
  {pol1, pol2, pol3, pol4} = TestPolynomials[TestLength];
  tmp = Timing[D[LongTestA[pol1, pol2, pol3, pol4], r];][[1]];
  Return[tmp];
];

TestB[_] := Block[{tmp, pol1, pol2, pol3, pol4},
  {pol1, pol2, pol3, pol4} = TestPolynomials[TestLength];
  tmp = Timing[D[LongTestB[pol1, pol2, pol3, pol4], r];][[1]];
  Return[tmp];
];
```

And finally the timings...

```
TestA /@ Range[20]
(* {1.73211, 1.90012, 1.81211, 1.82811, 1.85212, 1.91612, 1.84012, 
    1.84812, 1.83211, 1.85612, 1.50009, 1.5961,  1.70411, 1.75211, 
    1.77611, 1.78811, 1.78811, 1.79611, 1.79611, 1.81211} *)

TestB /@ Range[20]
(* {1.46009, 1.46409, 1.47209, 1.46809, 1.48409, 1.48009, 1.46809, 
    1.48009, 1.47209, 1.47209, 1.6561,  1.36009, 1.40409, 1.43609, 
    1.47209, 1.45209, 1.45609, 1.46409, 1.46009, 1.45609} *)
```