# How to customize derivative behavior via upvalues?

Tags: upvalues

I'm having trouble getting customized derivatives (defined using upvalues) to behave in sane ways. By this I mean that I'd like to define a derivative using an upvalue and then have Mathematica apply all derivative rules it normally would, delegating to the upvalues when appropriate. For example.

```
X /: D[X[x_], y_] := A KroneckerDelta[x,y]
Y /: D[Y[x_], y_] := B KroneckerDelta[x,y]
D[X[x], x]        (* Gives the Expected Answer:  A *)
D[X[x] + Y[x], x] (* Desired Output:   A + B  *)
D[X[x] Y[x], x]   (* Desired Output:   A Y[x] + X[x] B   *)
```

For the latter two, I get `X'[x] + Y'[x]` and `Y[x] X'[x] + X[x] Y'[x]`. I'm not understanding why the upvalues aren't kicking in. A similar question was asked [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14372/problem-overloading-d-using-upvalues), but I couldn't adjust it for my problem.

**Update:**

It looks like I didn't specify my problem in enough detail. To give a better sense of the direction I'm looking, see this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41907/how-to-take-derivative-of-parameterized-coordinate). My (present) understanding of `Derivative` suggests it cannot achieve what I want since the arguments to my functions are abstract indices (e.g. multiple arguments are implicit).

Consider a (discrete) joint probability $p_{XY}(i,j)$ where $i$ and $j$ are indexes (with unspecified ranges) that represent the possible values. Now, consider a marginal distribution $p_X(i) = \sum_j p_{XY}(i,j)$.  Each $p_X(i)$ depends on all of the $p_{XY}(j,k)$ with $j = i$. I was hoping to declare the derivatives of $p_{XY}(i,j)$ and $p_X(i)$ with respect to $p_{XY}(k,l)$ (treating each $p_{XY}(i,j)$ as independent variables). Then, I wanted to be able to differentiate any generic expression involving those functions. Mathematically, this is the behavior:

$$
\frac{\partial p_{XY}(i,j)}{\partial p_{XY}(k,l)} = \delta_{ij} \delta_{jk} \qquad\qquad
\frac{\partial p_X(i)}{\partial p_{XY}(k,l)} = \delta_{ik}
$$

Here is a toy expression I'd like to differentiate:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial p_{XY}(k,l)} \left[ p_{XY}(i,j) p_X(i)^2 \right] = \delta_{ik} \delta_{jl}\, p_X(i)^2 + 2 p_{XY}(i,j)\, p_X(i) \, \delta_{ik}
$$

The above is just an application of the product rule, so it's pretty straight-forward to do these calculations by hand, once the derivatives of the primitives are specified. However, I don't want to re-specify all the rules of differentiation. Somehow I'd like to tell Mathematica to use its own system, while incorporating my primitives.

Things I've tried...

```
pXY /: D[pXY[i_, j_], pXY[k_, l_]] := Simplify[KroneckerDelta[i, k] KroneckerDelta[j, l]]
pX /: D[pX[i_], pXY[j_, k_]] := KroneckerDelta[i, j]
D[pXY[i, j] pX[i]^2, pXY[k, l]]   (* Undesirably returns 0 *)
```

I think I understand why (via pattern matching) this gives 0. Another attempt:

```
pXY /: D[pXY[i_, j_], pXY[k_, l_]] := Simplify[KroneckerDelta[i, k] KroneckerDelta[j, l]]
pX[i_] := MySumX[pXY[i, j], {i, j}]
MySum /: D[MySum[s_, {i_, j_}], pXY[k_, l_]] := D[s /. {i -> k, j -> l}, pXY[k, l]]
MySumX /: D[MySumX[s_, {i_, j_}], pXY[k_, l_]] := D[s /. {i -> k}, pXY[k, l]]

D[pX[i], pXY[i, k]]  (* Result is correct *)
D[pXY[i, j] + pX[i], pXY[k, l]] (* Result is not correct *)
```

Hopefully its clearer now how the original question relates to what I'm truly after. Just to keep it fun, here is another expression I'd like to differentiate:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial p_{XY}(k,l)} \sum_{i,j} p_{XY}(i,j)\log \frac{ p_{XY}(i,j)}{p_X(i) p_Y(j)}$$

Comment: You haven't defined any values for `D[X[x] + Y[x], x]` so *Mathematica* computes it as normal, giving `X'[x] + Y'[x]`. Note that the result is in terms of `Derivative` not `D`. I think you will be better off defining your custom derivatives as subvalues of `Derivative`, e.g. `X'[_] := A; Y'[_] := B;`

Comment: I'm not sure if I can do it via Derivative. I've updated the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

In my original answer (which I have left below for entertainment value) I asserted that it would be difficult to make it work with upvalues using `D`, but Tom has reminded me of the `NonConstants` option. When the symbols listed as NonConstants are differentiated they remain as expressions with head `D`:

```
D[a x, x, NonConstants -> {a}]
(*  a + x D[a, x, NonConstants -> {a}]  *)
```

This means that it is perfectly possible to use the upvalues approach suggested in the question, all that is required is to extend the pattern with a `BlankNullSequence[]` to allow for the presence of the option.

```
pXY /: D[pXY[i_, j_], pXY[k_, l_], ___] := Simplify[KroneckerDelta[i, k] KroneckerDelta[j, l]]
pX /: D[pX[i_], pXY[j_, k_], ___] := KroneckerDelta[i, j]

SetOptions[D, NonConstants -> {pXY, pX}];

D[pXY[i, j] pX[i]^2, pXY[k, l]]
(*  KroneckerDelta[i, k] KroneckerDelta[j, l] pX[i]^2 + 
  2 KroneckerDelta[i, k] pX[i] pXY[i, j]  *)
```

**Original answer**

In response to the updated question:

I think it will be very difficult to make it work using rules based on `D`. This simple example shows the problem:

```
a /: D[a[x], x] := 1

D[a[x], x]
(* 1 *)

D[2 a[x], x]
(* 2 a'[x] *)
```

Because there is no special rule defined for `D[2 a[x], x]` it is evaluated as normal, giving `2 Derivative[1][a][x]`. You could of course add lots more upvalues to deal with different expressions, but you will end up effectively rewriting the rules of differentiation.

A better solution is to create your special rules based on `Derivative`, like this:

```
pXY[i_, j_]'[pXY[k_, l_]] := Simplify[KroneckerDelta[i, k] KroneckerDelta[j, l]]
pX[i_]'[pXY[j_, k_]] := KroneckerDelta[i, j]
```

You will note that your example does not appear to work, however:

```
D[pXY[i, j] pX[i]^2, pXY[k, l]]
(* 0 *)
```

What's going on here is that `D` sees that the function does not appear to depend on the differentiation variable, so it returns 0 immediately. It's the same as `D[Sin, x]` returning 0 while `D[Sin[x], x]` returns `Cos[x]`. The solution is to make the expression explicitly a function of the differentiation variable:

```
D[pXY[i, j][pXY[k, l]] pX[i][pXY[k, l]]^2, pXY[k, l]]
(* KroneckerDelta[i, k] KroneckerDelta[j, l] pX[i][pXY[k, l]]^2 + 
 2 KroneckerDelta[i, k] pX[i][pXY[k, l]] pXY[i, j][pXY[k, l]] *)
```

This works, but has made the notation messy. A possible solution is to define your own version of `D` which automatically converts `func` to `func[var]` before differentiating, and then converts `func[var]` back to `func` afterwards.

```
myD[expr_, var_] := D[expr /. (p_pX | p_pXY) :> p[var], var] /. (p_pX | p_pXY)[var] :> p
```

You now have:

```
myD[pXY[i, j] pX[i]^2, pXY[k, l]] 
(* KroneckerDelta[i, k] KroneckerDelta[j, l] pX[i]^2 + 
 2 KroneckerDelta[i, k] pX[i] pXY[i, j] *)
```

Comment: This works quite nicely, and I was able to adapt it to my problem. Could you comment on whether or not using NonConstants in D[] would work as well?

Comment: @Tom, I had completely forgotten about `NonConstants`. That means you **can** use upvalues as you suggested. Update coming up.

Answer (score 3):

Using information from the question you've linked:

```
Derivative[1][X][_] = A
Derivative[1][Y][_] = B

D[X[x], x]        
D[X[x] + Y[x], x] 
D[X[x] Y[x], x]
```

> ```
> A
> A+B
> B X[x] + A Y[x]
> ```

Nothing else is required since `D[X[x], y]` is from definition `0`.