# Chain rule when taking derivatives with UpValues

Tags: functions, function-construction, differentials

I have a summation function, for which I have defined derivation via

```
Custom`sum /: D[Custom`sum[idx_, a_, b_, exprs_], y_] := Custom`sum[idx, a, b D[expr, y]];
```

where `idx` is the index with bounds `a` and `b`.
This does not seem to work, though when the sum is inside another function. For example, I get

```
D[Sqrt[Custom`sum[idx, 1, 2, func[idx, y]]], y]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

where via chain rule I would expect

```
1/Sqrt[Custom`sum[idx, 1, 2, func[idx, y]]]*1/2*Custom`sum[idx, 1, 2, Derivative[0,1][func][idx, y]]]
```

To give an even simpler example, look what happens with `Plus`

```
D[f[g[x,1]+g[x,2]],x]
(* (f^′)[g[x,1]+g[x,2]] ((g^(1,0))[x,1]+(g^(1,0))[x,2]) *)
```

How can I achieve the same with

```
D[f[sum[g[x,i]]],x]
(* (f^′)[sum[g[x,i]]] (sum^′)[g[x,i]] (g^(1,0))[x,i] *)
```

Is there a way to get the chain rule to work for these cases?

Comment: I fixed the typos in your question because I believe it is a good one. I currently see no direct way to do this, but defining `UpValues` to `sum` with `D` will not work. If you have a wrapping function like your `Sqrt`, then the intermediate expressions only consist of `Derivative` and there is no `D` anymore that matches AFAIK. But I might of course be wrong.

Comment: You might also want to look at [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42488/how-to-customize-derivative-behavior-via-upvalues) as it is very similar to yours, but I'm not sure your problem can be solved with the information there. So don't claim it is a duplicate, but it might be worth reading.

Answer (score 7):

There is a system option that provides a list of excluded functions for differentiation. If you add `` Custom`sum `` to the list you should be able to use your definition as expected.

```
exf = "ExcludedFunctions" /. ("DifferentiationOptions" /. SystemOptions[]);

SetSystemOptions[
  "DifferentiationOptions" -> "ExcludedFunctions" -> Append[exf, Custom`sum]];

Custom`sum /: D[Custom`sum[idx_, a_, b_, exprs_], y_] := Custom`sum[idx, a, b, D[exprs, y]]

D[Custom`sum[idx, 1, 2, func[idx, y]], y] // InputForm

(* Custom`sum[idx, 1, 2, Derivative[0, 1][func][idx, y]] *)

D[Sqrt @ Custom`sum[idx, 1, 2, func[idx, y]], y] // InputForm

(* Custom`sum[idx, 1, 2, Derivative[0, 1][func][idx, y]] /
  (2*Sqrt[Custom`sum[idx, 1, 2, func[idx, y]]]) *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: Thanks! It seems, though, as if the other definitions for `Custom'sum` are messing with this method, so that I get zero again for the `Sqrt` case. Therefore I'll probably stick with the `NonConstant` solution I posted below.

Answer (score 1):

The question halirutan linked to was very helpful. By setting

```
SetOptions[D, NonConstants -> {Custom`sum}];
```

a `D[Custom'sum[idx,a,b,func[idx,y],y,NonConstants->{Custom'sum}]` appears during the evaluation of the derivative, and the UpValue, slightly modified to include the `NonConstants->{Custom'sum}`, works again:

```
SetOptions[D, NonConstants -> {Custom`sum}];

Custom`sum /: D[Custom`sum[idx_, a_, b_, exprs_], y_, c___] := Custom`sum[idx, a, b , D[exprs, y, c]];


D[Sqrt @ Custom`sum[idx, 1, 2, func1[idx, x]], x] // InputForm

(* Custom`sum[idx, 1, 2, Derivative[0, 1][func1][idx, x]]/(2*Sqrt[Cutom`sum[idx, 1, 2, func1[idx, x]]]) *)
```